# XSLT: Adding multiple attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to add multiple attributes into a single node without hard coding the names. The **input xml** looks like this:

```
<bom>
    <columns>
        <column id="0">Name</column>
        <column id="1">ID</column>
        <column id="2">Description</column>
    </columns>
    <rows>
        <row number="0" level="0" position="">
            <cell column="0">FooName1</cell>
            <cell column="1">1000</cell>
            <cell column="2">FooDescription1</cell>
        </row>
        <row number="1" level="1" position="">
            <cell column="0">FooName2</cell>
            <cell column="1">2000</cell>
            <cell column="2">FooDescription2</cell>
        </row>
        <row number="2" level="1" position="">
            <cell column="0">FooName3</cell>
            <cell column="1">3000</cell>
            <cell column="2">FooDescription3</cell>
        </row>
    </rows>
</bom>
```

I would like the **output xml** to look something like this:

```
<xml>
    <Item Name="FooName1"
            ID="1000"
            Description="FooDescription1"
            >
        <BOM>
            <Child Name="FooName2"
            ID="2000"
            Description="FooDescription2"
            />
            <Child Name="FooName3"
            ID="3000"
            Description="FooDescription3"
            />
        </BOM>
    </Item>
</xml>
```

My XSLT (version 1.0) so far looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="bom">
    <impxml>
      <Item>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="columns/column" />
      </Item>
    </impxml>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="columns/column">
    <!-- <xsl:value-of select="."/> Fetch all column values -->
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:attribute name="TEST">TEST</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`<xsl:attribute name="">` will only accept one hardcoded name. How can I iterate through all values in columns\column and add them as attributes to the same Item or Child node?

I am new to XSLT, so I appreciate any input/help here. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `<xsl:attribute name="a"/><xsl:attribute name="b"/>`?

Comment: Where does the attribute name `ItemNo` come from for the two `child` elements?

Comment: @TimC: Sorry about the confusion, it should have been 'Description'. 'ItemNo' was a typo. I have corrected this.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Yunnosch, but wouldn't your suggestion mean that I am hard coding the names: a and b?

Comment: What I propose is not to try to make multiple attributes with a single xsl:attribute. Instead use more of them, optionally from a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `ancestor::*` to retrieve `<column>` values at top. Then use `{path}` for dynamic attribute name which is equivalent to `<xsl:value-of select="path" />` outside of attribute. Both are matched by corresponding `@id` and `@column` values using `xsl:variable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="bom">
    <impxml>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="rows/row" />
    </impxml>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rows/row">
      <Item>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="cell" />
      </Item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cell">
    <xsl:variable name="curr_col"><xsl:value-of select="@column"/></xsl:variable>      
      <xsl:attribute name="{ancestor::bom/columns/column[@id=$curr_col]}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<impxml>
   <Item Name="FooName1" ID="1000" Description="FooDescription1"/>
   <Item Name="FooName2" ID="2000" Description="FooDescription2"/>
   <Item Name="FooName3" ID="3000" Description="FooDescription3"/>
</impxml>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help.